# How to make these Mocap Animation FBX's work with Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, fbx, animator, mo-cap

The ones here (any of them)... http://dancedb.eu/main/performances

I'm trying to figure out how to apply these FBX's to my humanoid, rigged model in Unity.

When I import the FBX and toggle it open, it shows this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcIBu.png

and I can't hit Ctrl+D on any of those to Duplicate it into an *.anim (That's what a Google search recommended)

So, where am I going wrong? How do I apply these animations to my rigged humanoid character in Unity? I'm quite a noob, so please excuse me. Been Googling for a while...

Comment: I dont think "legacy" animations can be duplicated in unity - also noting that using unity 2020 alpha can be known to effect behaviors in unknown ways..

Comment: I see. Any recommendations for alternative approach? Googling also. I'm using 2019.3.0a7

Comment: 2019.3 has come a long way since alpha 7...   what exactly do you want to duplicate them for?

Comment: When I Googled about how to apply FBX animation to a character, people said to use Animation controller and to convert the FBX to an *.anim by Duplicating its contents. But all I'm trying to do is ultimately apply the FBX animation, so maybe there is a better way that doesn't require any duplication

Comment: you should just be able to use them as they are.

Comment: How? Sorry. When I add an "Animation" component to the model I want to apply the animation to, it asks for an *.anim. I don't know how to make the model animate simply from the mocap FBX file. =|

Comment: Make an animator and put them in there.. works for me

Comment: Okay sorry, but put what in where? For instance, if I have an 'Animation' component on the 3D Model I want to animate, there are no viable 'Animation Clips' that show up after the FBX is imported into the Unity project. And if I create an Animation Controller for my 3D Model and add a State there, it also doesn't show anything I can use as a state since there is nothing in *anim format for it to take. Can you please be super specific? I feel extremely dumb.

Comment: As I said, create an "Animator" not an "Animation" ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Humanoid Retargeting](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Retargeting.html).

You may have better luck using the BVH files from the website you linked and using a [BVH importer here](https://github.com/ousttrue/UniHumanoid).